# Spring customize error page return no explicit mapping for /error

Tags: java, spring

I want to customize error page from spring like this:

```
@Controller
public class Error implements ErrorController{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/error")
    public ModelAndView error(){

        return new ModelAndView("error");

    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath(){
        return "/error";
    }

}
```

`ModelAndView("error")` - error is an `jsp` in `WEB-INF/jsp/`

When I try to trigger error by accessing an invalid link: `mydom.com/invalidlink` is not printed my `error.jsp`.

Insted is printed this message:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

null
There was an unexpected error (type=null, status=null).
```

How I customize error page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i post my code for your help

```
@Controller
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController  
    @RequestMapping("/error") 
    public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) { 
        return "error";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }
}
```

my code is working , there is only one difference between your and my code

```
public String handleError()
```

it's return string and your case

```
public ModelAndView error()
```

return ModelAndVIew.....